# QGLWidget::renderText bounding box

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, graphics, qt4

Is it possible to get the bounding box of the output of **QGLWidget::renderText()** in logical or window coordinates? How?

Comment: I do not think this is possible, at least not cleanly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use QFontMetrics::boundingRect(). Also maybe you'll need to consider how it handles the newline character (\n).

There's an overloaded [QFontMetrics::boundingRect()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qfontmetrics.html#boundingRect-5) that returns the bounding rect of the given text within a specified rectangle as well.

Comment: Yes, it works and the result would be in window coordinate as expected.
Thanks for the answer!